# Parametric Equation of Triangular polygon bounded by 3 sides

Tags: triangles, parametric, polygons

Hello there :) I need help with my assignment.

I need to construct a parametric equation that defines a triangular polygon bounded by 3 segments. This is meant to be as extra credit.

However, I do not understand much about planes and polygons and thus I need help. Really appreciate all the help i can get on this. There are 5 questions for the extra credit but  I managed to solve all except this last one.

**Question:** Write parametric equations $x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v), where u,v \in [0,1]$ defining a triangular polygon which is bounded by three segments defined by

$x=1+2u\;\;\;\;$    $y=1+u\;\;\;\;$      $z=1-u\;\;\;\;$       $u,v \in [0,1]$

$x=3-u\;\;\;\;$      $y=2+u\;\;\;\;$    $z=4u\;\;\;\;\;$        $\;u,v \in [0,1]$

$x=2-u\;\;\;\;$      $y=3-u\;\;\;\;$    $z=4-3u\;\;\;\;$      $u,v \in [0,1]$

Thank you all so much for any valuable input that you have to offer. I really appreciate this!

Comment: How much do you know already? (you can simply solve the equations to find the 3 intersection points -> triangle vertices; then find the parametric equation)

Comment: You should post the problem statement as text (use Latex for math formula), not images.

Comment: Sorry about your grandparent's passing, but this piece of information doesn't really count as context to your question.

Comment: @user202729 The vertices are already given.

Comment: @amd They are parametric equations of the 3 line segments of the triangle (note: the editor did not correctly convert the image to text). It's still necessary to do something to get the vertices.

Comment: @user202729 Not really. They can be read directly from the three sets of equations. Take a closer look at the endpoints of each segment.